# non-standard conditional sort algorithm STL c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

I am studying STL and have found [this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/course-reader/Ch7_STLAlgorithms.pdf) very interesting PDF from Stanford with tasks. One of the tasks is to sort a list of songs but in such a way that songs labelled as "My song" were always first in the list.

So, if we have:

```
vector <string> song{ "Viva", "Pompeii", "My song", "We remain", "My song", "It is time" };
```

The output should be:

```
My song, My song ... (in ascending or descending order);
```

I have solved the problem by using  `iter_swap`

Here is my code:

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <numeric>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;


    void print(vector <string> song) {
        for (vector <string> ::iterator it = song.begin(), end = song.end(); it != end; ++it) {
            cout << *it << " ";
        }
    }

    int main() {
        vector <string> song{ "Viva", "Pompeii", "My song", "We remain", "My song", "It is time" };
        vector <string> ::iterator start = song.begin();

        for (vector <string> ::iterator begin = song.begin(), end = song.end(); begin != end; ++begin){
            if (*begin == "My song") {
                iter_swap(start, begin);
                ++start;
            }
        }
        sort(start, song.end());
        print(song);
        cin.get();
        }
```

But before that, I had been struggling for a while to solve the problem by using only `sort` algorithm. Unfortunately, I did not come up with the solution. Could you say if it is possible to write a sorting function `compare`which would solve the task? I am not sure if it is possible, since `sort` just does simple ordering. Am I right?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool compare(string x, string y) {
    // What to write here?
}

void print(vector <string> song) {
    for (vector <string> ::iterator it = song.begin(), end = song.end(); it != end; ++it) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    vector <string> song{ "Viva", "Pompeii", "My song", "We remain", "My song", "It is time" };

    sort(start, song.end(), compare);
    print(song);
    cin.get();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You just have to make sure that the string `"My song"` compares less than any other string.

```
bool compare(std::string const& x, std::string const& y)
{
    // if y == "My Song", then x can't come before it
    if (y == "My song") return false;

    // we already know y != "My Song", so if x does, then we know it should come before y
    if (x == "My song") return true;

    // neither x nor y == "My Song", so just fall back to a normal comparison.
    return x < y;    
}
```

By the way, your original idea was a fine one. But what you were doing was a partition. There's an algorithm in the standard library for that too.

```
auto start = std::partition(song.begin(), song.end(),
    [](std::string const& s) { return s == "My song"; });
std::sort(start, song.end());
```